# select rows where column contains same data in more than one record

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have a table that has a column called `article_title`. Let's say the table name is `articles`. I need to find out the records where the `article_title` data is the same on more than one record.

Here's what I've got:

```
select a.* 
from articles a 
where a.article_title = (select article_title 
                         from articles 
                         where article_title = a.article_title 
                         AND a.id <> articles.id)
```

Answer (score 53):

HAVING is a great aggregate filter. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) For example, select the article_titles with more than on occurrence:

```
SELECT count(*), article_title
FROM articles
GROUP BY article_title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Adding columns to the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses allow you to locate duplicates based on a composite key of multiple columns.

Comment: @jkushner: but beware of the quirks (or bugs as some may see it) in MySQL's implementation of `GROUP BY`: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: This seems to not answer the question completely, because this will state which article titles are duplicated, but it won't, for instance, be able to return the IDs of those records, or any other information attached to them.

Answer (score 18):

Your problem can be solved with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE article_title IN (SELECT *
                        FROM (SELECT article_title
                              FROM article
                              GROUP BY article_title
                              HAVING COUNT(article_title) > 1)
                        AS a);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because it actually returns the rows that have the duplicates

Answer (score 4):

> have a table that has a column called article_title. Let's say the
>   table name is articles. I need to find out the records where the
>   article_title data is the same on more than one record.

Sound like to me you also need to have the id because you want to find records based on `article_title` because you have duplicates

**Basic MIN/MAX with GROUP BY (you will miss id's when more then 2 duplicates)**

```
SELECT 
  MIN(id) -- for FIFO id's (first id by duplicate)
, MAX(id) -- for LIFO id's (last id by duplicate)
, article_title
, COUNT(*)  
FROM
 articles
WHERE -- Maybe to filter out '' or IS NOT NULL
 article_title != '' AND article_title IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
 article_title ASC
HAVING
 COUNT(*) >= 2
;
```

**Or back to denormalisation to generate an CSV for LIFO id's (older id's by duplicates) but you know all id's here..**

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY ASC SEPARATOR ',') -- change to DESC if want the last record first
, article_title
, COUNT(*)  
FROM
 articles
GROUP BY
 article_title ASC
HAVING
 COUNT(*) >= 2
;
```