# Select when group by contains more than one row with the same value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to write a query that returns one row from table A whenever a column in joined table B contains multiple distinct values for a single matching row in table A. (A -> B is a 1 -> many relationship.) I built a SQL fiddle to demonstrate this in context: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83952/1

In this fiddle, the `design` column of the `perf_ticket_type` table should be the same for every `ticket_type` that has the same `perf_id`, but I'm trying to select only the instances where it doesn't. So for `perf_id` 3, there is more than one unique `design` being returned with the query I'm using currently.

What I want as my result is the two columns of the `performance` table only for `perf_id` 3, based on the multiple values of `design` for that `perf_id` in the joined table.

I've been frustrated by understanding GROUP BY in the past, so I'm unsure if there's something different I could be doing here to get my desired result. At the moment, I think I can select what I have in the fiddle into a temp table and then do *another* select on *that* with a `GROUP BY perf_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to get what I want (as per [select rows where column contains same data in more than one record](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54187/)), but that seems like it's an extra step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is right but you need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT design) > 1`

Like this:

```
WITH multi_design_perfs AS
(SELECT b.perf_id 
FROM perf_ticket_type b
GROUP BY b.perf_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.design) > 1
)
SELECT m.perf_id, 
    STUFF((select ', ' + CAST(b.design AS varchar(10))
     FROM perf_ticket_type b 
     WHERE b.perf_id = m.perf_id
     ORDER BY b.design
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')
FROM multi_design_perfs m
;
```

Comment: Oh hey, that CTE seems like a great way to avoid the temp table. And originally I had no idea what you were doing with STUFF() and XML, but now that I consider it, that's a fascinating solution that could work for an entirely different project I have. Thanks!

Comment: STUFF() is just to remove the leading comma. The FOR XML PATH bit does the concatenation.